# Como puedo validar fechas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas estoy realizando un formulario donde tengo dos campos de fechas pero nose como hacer para validar estos campos. Tengo un campo que es la fecha de ingreso al laboratorio y otro campo que es una fecha de devolución. Tendría que validar que el usuario tengo que ingresar una fecha si o si posterior a la de ingreso.

Estos son mis campos en la vista:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
         <label for="entry">Fecha de Ingreso a Laboratorio</label> 
         <input type="text" name="entry" id="entry"
         class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Fecha De Ingreso" required readonly
 </div>
              
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
         <label for="deliver">Fecha de Devolucion</label>
         <input type="text" name="deliver" id="deliver" class="form-control form-control-sm" required placeholder="Entrega al Cliente" readonly>
  </div>
```

Y para darle el formato de fechas estoy usando bootstrap y jquery:

```
<script>
$('#entry').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    format: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$('#deliver').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es tomar la fecha de tu ingreso y pasas este valor a la propiedad minDate utilizando la clase Date que trae Javascript nativamente

```
const fecha = $('#entry').val();
$('...tu input de fecha').datepicker({
   minDate: new Date(fecha)
})
```

esto tomará como fecha mínima la fecha escogida en tu input de `#entry` a tu nuevo input de datepicker, permitiendo que no sea posible seleccionar fechas anteriores a la fecha de ingreso

Comment: De este modo automaticamente se valida tambien la otra fecha no?

Comment: Entiendo que requieres es tratar que el usuario no seleccione una fecha anterior a la de tu ingreso, con eso estaríamos asegurándonos de que no haya una seleccione anterior a dicha fecha ¿a que otra fecha necesitas que también se valide lo mismo? puedes utilizar esto en todos los datepicker que quieres pero es claro que debes inicializar esos datepicker después de haber capturado tu fecha de ingreso